# Scikit Learn, Recognizing hand-written digits, mistake in given code example

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am running the code found on the "Recognizing Hand-Written Digits" code on the Scikit Learn page [(click here for exact code)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-classification-plot-digits-classification-py).

When I run the following line:

```
classifier.fit(data[:n_samples / 2], digits.target[:n_samples / 2])
```

I get the following error in my terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_digits_classification.py", line 35, in <module>
    classifier.fit(data[:n_samples / 2], digits.target[:n_samples / 2])
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Why is this happening? How do I get the code example to work?

Comment: Try replacing `n_samples / 2` with `int(n_samples / 2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Python 2, the operator `/` with `int` arguments will return an `int`. With Python 3, the operator `/` will always return a `float`, even with `int` arguments. To get an `int` with Python 3 use the operator `//` like at `6//3`.

So your code would be:

```
classifier.fit(data[:n_samples // 2], digits.target[:n_samples // 2])
```

And so on.